# Two site Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hamiltonian

So my question is I have this Hamiltonian:
$$ H = \sum_i \epsilon_i \sigma^+_i\sigma^-_i + \sum_{i\neq j} V_{ij} \sigma^+_i \sigma^-_j, $$
and I want to write it out for two site.
Is this correct?:
$$\sigma^+_1 \sigma^-_1 + \sigma^+_2 \sigma^+_2 + V_{12} \sigma^+_1 \sigma^+_2 +V_{21} \sigma^+_2 \sigma^-_1$$

I hear that the Heisenberg model can help me solve this problem as the Hamiltonians are similar. If so, how?

Note: This is a quantum mechanical Hamiltonian. Therefore, the Hamiltonian is a linear operator that acts on states.

Comment: You should always have terms that look like $\sigma^+_i\sigma^-_j$, not $\sigma^+\sigma^+$. Try writing the Hamiltonian as a $4\times 4$ matrix and diagonalising it.

Comment: @MarkMitchison which was my next question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ in the first two terms. You should also have $\sigma_2^-$ in the third term, rather than $\sigma_2^+$.

EDIT: I assume that $V_{12}=V_{21}$. $(\sigma_{x1}+i\sigma_{y1})(\sigma_{x1}-i\sigma_{y1})=\sigma_{x1}^2+\sigma_{y1}^2+i\sigma_{y1}\sigma_{x1}-i\sigma_{x1}\sigma_{y1}=2+2\sigma_{z1}$.

$(\sigma_{x1}+i\sigma_{y1})(\sigma_{x2}-i\sigma_{y2})+(\sigma_{x2}+i\sigma_{y2})(\sigma_{x1}-i\sigma_{y1})=2\sigma_{x1}\sigma_{x2}+2\sigma_{y1}\sigma_{y2}=2\vec{\sigma_{1}}\vec{\sigma_{2}}-2\sigma_{z1}\sigma_{z2}$.

Comment: but apart from that, it is a two site Hamiltonian? Also, how does Heisenberg model relate to it?

Comment: it depends on experimentation whether $V_{12}=V_{21}$

Comment: @T Abraham: I am not sure, but this equality may follow from hermiticity of the Hamiltonian. If this equality does not hold, I am not sure I can be of further help.

Comment: are you referring to its relationship to Heisenberg model?

Comment: @T Abraham: Yes - $\vec{\sigma_1}\vec{\sigma_2}$